Movie/TV Show where human asks anthropomorphic character if it symbolizes something
I think it was TV, but it might be a movie. It was comedic but I think it was more surrealistic black comedy or comedy/drama. I think it's mainstream, American, and fairly recent, definitely after 2000.
The way I remember it, a human and some anthropomorphic character (possibly some kind of animal) are sitting together while the latter is talking to some other characters. I think the show usually only uses humans, because the anthropomorphic character's presence is unusual. The conversation ends and the human, who was previously silent, gives it a knowing look and asks it something like: "Are you a metaphor? Like, do you symbolize something?" It looks at the human for a second and then the scene ends.
It was meant as a mild breaking of the fourth wall, acknowledging the trope of fictional characters representing philosophical ideas.
Does that ring any bells for anyone?

Maybe Donny Darko? It has some scenes with a Bunny costume.

Wilfred also comes to mind. But remembering what the creature was exactly would really help...

Probably not Donnie Darko if the anthropomorphic character was talking to other people.  Fred (the bunny) pretty much only spoke / appeared to Donnie.
